# WidgetKit not calling urlSessionDidFinishEvents

Tags: watchos, widgetkit, watchos-9

I'm trying to implement downloading timeline data in a widget and so I created a background `URLSession` with a corresponding data task to download the JSON:

```swift
let session = URLSession(
  configuration: .background(withIdentifier: identifier),
  delegate: self,
  delegateQueue: nil
)

let request = URLRequest(url: ...)
session.dataTask(with: request).resume()
```

On my widget I then added the `onBackgroundURLSessionEvents` to store the completion handler, as per the Apple docs:

```swift
.onBackgroundURLSessionEvents { identifier in
  return SessionCache.shared.isValid(for: identifier)
} _: { identifier, completion in
  let data = SessionCache.shared.sessionData(for: identifier)
  data.sessionCompletion = completion
}
```

However, neither the `urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)` nor the `onBackgroundURLSessionEvents` methods are called.  When the network download completes, it just calls the normal `urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)` method.

I'm clearly missing something here, but I'm just not seeing what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's documentation isn't 100% clear on this, but you need to use `URLSession.downloadTask` instead of `dataTask` for background sessions. `URLSessionDataTask`s deliver bytes to those specific delegate methods in your in-memory process. Background download & upload tasks are handed off to `nsurlsessiond` and only delivered back to your app when they are fully resolved.

Comment: Ugh, I knew that and totally forgot about it.  Thank you so much, it's working great now.